# Lipo alternate for linux

Tags: linux, tools, binary, ios

Currently, I'm using **lipo** tool to extract the arch type from a fat iOS binary on a Mac OS. Now, I want to do the same on the **linux** **platform** **for the** **iOS** **binaries**, i.e. extract a given arch type from a fat iOS binary on a linux platform. However, lipo support is not available on Linux.

Any suggestions how can I achieve the same? Any alternate of lipo for linux which does the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a port of Apple’s `cctools` to Linux, it should include `lipo`:

https://github.com/tpoechtrager/cctools-port